# Looping through dynamic textboxes inside dynamic panel (inside placeholder)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `placeholder` I use for dynamically creating textboxes as well as buttons used for removing these textboxes on the client side.

**Function for adding controls:**

```
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    Button btn = new Button { Text = "Remove" };
    btn.Click += btnRemove_Click;
    panel.Controls.Add(btn);
    panel.Controls.Add(new TextBox { ID = string.Concat("txtContractor", index) });
    placeHolder.Controls.Add(panel);
```

These controls are placed inside of a `panel` that does not have an ID. They are re-added whenever a post-back occurs so I don't think that is the issue.

My question is how would I format my foreach loop for getting the text from the textboxes inside of the panel

```
foreach (Control ctrl in placeHolder.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is Panel)
    {
        //for each control inside this panel
        //{
              //if it is textbox
              //{ 
                  //do whatever 
              //}
        //}
     }            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx).

```
foreach (Control ctrl in placeHolder.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is Panel)
    {
        // Get each ID and Text from TextBox
        var textBoxes = ctrl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                                     .Select(t => Tuple.Create(t.ID, t.Text))
                                     .ToList();

        foreach(var item in textBoxes)
        {
            //do whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is worked but for some reason the nested foreach loop only goes through it once, no matter how many textBoxes I add.

Comment: Try adding a `ToList`. If that doesn't work could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Never mind actually, it was a slight mistake with the way I was debugging, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating these controls (panels, buttons and textboxes) with your own code. Add a container (`List<TextBox>` or `Dictionary<string, TextBox>`) as a member of your `Page` class and add textboxes to this container as you create them. Then simply iterate over the container items to get each textbox.